# for loop is not calling restful api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code neat and clean

as you can see i have make a for loop and passing a[i] variable to the api
now what is happeing is for loop is is not hitting the api and going back to the loop. any solution?

```
 var a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','a10','a11','a12','a13','a14','a15','a16','a17','a18','a19','a20','a21','a22','a23','a24','a25','a26','a27','a28','a29','a30','a31','a32','a33','a34','a35','a36', 'a37']

 console.log(a)

for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){

          $http({
          url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=https://www.example.com/alpha/'+a[i]+'.html',
        method: "POST", 
            }).success(function(response){

        console.log(a[i]);
        console.log(response);
           });

}
```

Comment: That is a very bad approach. You should send the **entire list** to the server, not each element in a loop. Let the server take care of each element.

Comment: I can't send entire list ... Each URL is different for parsing the value from that specific url @koby

Comment: I can't understand why it is downvoted isn't there any solution?

Comment: You need to change your loop to `for(var i = 0; i <= a.length -1; i++){` so that it doesn't go beyond the array length.

Comment: @webbm let me try

Comment: @webbm no not working actually the problem is it not hitting the api and going back in loop

Comment: @doe Right, but the loop needed to be changed to what I suggested because of the array length, so keep that change. The issue with it not hitting the api is separate. What happens when you connect to the website in your browser?

Comment: when i am passing manually  url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=https://www.example.com/alpha/a1.html'... url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=https://www.example.com/alpha/a2.html', 

it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the for loop for the database call since it is asynchronous.Have a look on following code.

```
var a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4', ...];

  var i=0;
checkArrayLength();
function checkArrayLength(){
    if(i<a.length){
        makeRequest(a[i]);
    }
}

    function makeRequest(param1){

        $.ajax({
            url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=https://www.example.com/alpha/'+param1+'.html',
            method: "POST", 
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(a[i]);
              i=i+1;
              console.log(response);
                checkArrayLength();
            },
            error:function(response) {
              console.log(a[i]);
              i=i+1;
              console.log(response);
                checkArrayLength();
            }
        });

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use jQuery ajax to get the API called.
If this is the case, you should use `$.post` or `$.ajax`:

```
var a = ['a1','a2','a3','a4', ...];
console.log(a);
for(var i = 0; i <= a.length; i++){
  $.ajax({
    url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=https://www.example.com/alpha/'+a[i]+'.html',
    method: "POST", 
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(a[i]);
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
```

Otherwise, please share the `$http` function.

Comment: $Http is the angular function just like $,ajax in jQuey to call http method in AngularJs

Comment: My bad. Then, can you check if some specific iterations are failing, or all of them? (may be debugging the serverside code while calling it). You could be reaching the API correctly, but having issues in that side, and therefore never getting success called. You might also try handling the error response in JS, so see if it gets fired.

Comment: when i am passing manually url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=example.com/alpha/a1.html';... url: '/MyApp/getIt?urlofpage=example.com/alpha/a2.html';, it works fine

Comment: and it is even not reaching to the error response because it is not hitting the api